# Is there a way to detect/track only the front vehicle (preceding vehicle), instead of detecting all of the vehicles on the scene?(leading vehicle)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I want to detect/track the front vehicle. I have done a lot of research in this subject but I have not found a way to detect only the front vehicle.
I kinda went with a trajectory prediction model that gives this [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwSrS.png) and a normal detection/tracking model that kinda detects all vehicles in the scene which gave me this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaXHm.jpg) now I want to find the intersection between that trajectory predicted and one of the bounding boxes and that exact bounding box is the front vehicle. which I find it very hard to do. I just was wondering is there another way to detect the front vehicle besides all of this work I have done

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way for to detect/track only the front vehicle (for safe distance measurement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872245/is-there-a-way-for-to-detect-track-only-the-front-vehicle-for-safe-distance-mea)

Comment: No not really, I have posted that question too. it's the same problem. I want to increase the chances of people seing it and that's it